# Regex for rewriting URL

Tags: regex, wordpress

I have changed the URL to the posts on a blog, and now I need a regex to extract the new URL from the old when people are using the old URL.

The oldurl are typically: http://myblog.mysite.com/2011/03/27/name-of-my-blogg-post/

And the new urls are http://myblog.mysite.com/name-of-my-blogg-post/

I have a wordpress plugin called redirection that allows me to type in a regex and it will handle the forward etc. So what I need is a regex to detect the date in the url, and then give me the new URL without the month :)I

Comment: so is it PHP?  you just need a PHP function that takes the old URL and return the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a regexp

```
/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}
```

and use it to some replacing routine depending on the language you use.